# dining philosopher without deadlock

Tags: c, mutex, deadlock, semaphore

here is my code and I want to write it with out deadlock in c. How can I change it?

```
void *
philosopher (void * _args)
{
  /* Cast the args as struct with self identifier, semaphores */
  struct args *args = (struct args *) _args;
  int self = args->self;       /* unique thread identifier */
  int next = (self + 1) % SIZE;
  sem_wait (args->sems[self]); /* pick up left fork */
  sem_wait (args->sems[next]); /* pick up right fork */
  /* Critical section (eating) */
  sem_post (args->sems[next]); /* put down right fork */
  sem_post (args->sems[self]); /* put down left fork */
  /* Do other work and exit thread */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid deadlock in your code, you can use a semaphore with a non-zero initial value, to make sure that each philosopher picks up the forks in the same order.
By locking the forks with a semaphore, and having each philosopher acquire the lock prior to picking up the forks.

Here is an updated version of the code, that avoids deadlocks.

```
void *
philosopher (void * _args)
{
  /* Cast the args as struct with self identifier, semaphores */
  struct args *args = (struct args *) _args;
  int self = args->self;       /* unique thread identifier */
  int next = (self + 1) % SIZE;

  /* Acquire lock for forks */
  sem_wait (args->lock);

  /* Pick up left fork */
  sem_wait (args->sems[self]);

  /* Pick up right fork */
  sem_wait (args->sems[next]);

  /* Release lock for forks */
  sem_post (args->lock);

  /* Critical section (eating) */
  sem_post (args->sems[next]); /* put down right fork */
  sem_post (args->sems[self]); /* put down left fork */
  /* Do other work and exit thread */
}
```

Comment: The design approach to make sure that philosophers dine in a certain predetermined order seems to me like defeating the teaching goal of the dining philospher concept. The goal should be to allow each philosopher to dine if they are ready and the forks available . By the way, I always thought that the idea would work better aprroachable with chopsticks than with forks; some example of failed localisation there...

Comment: if you know better code please share it @Yunnosch

Comment: I was referrring to your explanation, not to the code. By the way, if all philosophers actually do use the same order, e.g. all of them take the left fork first, you still potentially end up in a deadlock.